# Alert manager add custom notification template

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-helm, prometheus-alertmanager, kube-prometheus-stack

I am using Alertmanager for Prometheus, installed through the Helm kube-prometheus-stack. I wish to add a new notification template. For code clarity reason, I am trying to isolate the
template on its own file. Doc leads me to do it through a secret. But I am a bit confused on the steps allowing to follows this through.

I create a secret containing my templates  named "alertmanager-templates".

```
apiVersion: v1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  kind: Secret                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
metadata:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  name: alertmanager-templates                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
data:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  mytemplate: Q2VjaSBlc3QgdW5lIGFsZXJ0ZQ==
```

Where base64 refers to "This is an alert"

I configure my notifications rules in a AlertManagerConfig crd, but this one does not support the addition of "templates"
So I add the templates in the AlertManagers crd, like this:

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      kind: Alertmanager                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        ...
spec:
  alertmanagerConfiguration:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    templates:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    - secret:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        key: alertmanager-templates                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        name: alertmanager-templates
```

And  then refer to the template in my receiver definition in AlertManagerConfig:

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1alpha1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                kind: AlertmanagerConfig  
spec:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  receivers:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  - name: sns                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
      snsConfigs:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
       message: '{{ template "mytemplate" . }}'
```

But I get the following error doing so:

`notify retry canceled due to unrecoverable error after 1 attempts: unexpected status code 400: Invalid parameter: Empty message","level":"error","msg":"Notify for alerts failed`

Is this not the way to be used ?